# Поиск в нескольких архивированных файлах

Tags: awk

Привет!
Почему при задании поиска в нескольких архивированных файлах gz, пример

```
zcat /var/log/nginx/**-main-access.log.[12]-[13].gz | grep PACK_ID=*** | grep pack_add | awk -F "||" '{print$5}' | cut -c1-2 | uniq -c
```

он не ищем в нескольких архивах, а только по отдельности файл, что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к тексту вопроса, вывод команды `$ ls -l /var/log/nginx/-main-access.log.[12]-[13].gz`. внести исправления можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: -rw-r----- 1 www-data adm 133686426 Авг 31 00:30 /var/log/nginx/**-main-access.log.13.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm 138163958 Авг 30 00:54 /var/log/nginx/**-main-access.log.14.gz

Comment: у вас есть два файла, соответствующие указанной вами маске. соответственно, второй части конвейера (`grep PACK_ID=*`) попадёт всё содержимое. а звёздочку, кстати, имеет смысл экранировать. иначе вместо неё будут подставлены имена файлов в текущем каталоге. либо так: `PACK_ID=\*`, либо так: `PACK_ID='*'`, либо так: `'PACK_ID=*'`

Comment: Нет, я специально убрал iD, в целях конфиденциальности, но в принципе ни чего это не даст для злонамеренных мошенников) поэтому укажу grep PACK_ID=50003. Это значение важное и фиксированное

Comment: так в чём вопрос-то тогда? как я и написал, под маску подпадают два файла. распакованное содержимое этих двух файлов поступает второй части конвейера. вас что-то не устраивает в конечном выводе вашего конвейера?

Comment: Ошибку выдает
zcat  /var/log/nginx/??-main-access.log.[12]-[13].gz | grep PACK_ID=50003 | grep pack_add | awk -F "||" '{print$5}' | cut -c1-2 | uniq -c
gzip: /var/log/nginx/??-main-access.log.[12]-[13].gz: No such file or directory

Comment: значит, неправильно маску указываете. и под неё не подпадает ни один файл.

Comment: Хорошо, я указываю и так и сяк. main-access.log.[12]-[13].gz main-access.log.[12-13].gz . не работает